# Render js action and pass local

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a partial form that functions as a follow/unfollow button. When I loop through a list of stores, I have a button to follow/unfollow each.

The form submits with `:remote => true` and I want to respond by rendering the div containing the change state of the button for that particular store.

```
def follow_from_index
  @store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
  current_user.vote_for(@store)
  render action: 'toggle_index'
end
```

I'm now setting the id for each containing div to be the AR Id of the store: `id="<%= store.id %>"`.

I was hoping I could then do something like this for `toggle_index`:

```
$("<%= store.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript render('favorite_index') %>");
```

Whereby I could pass the `toggle_index` action a local variable of the store in question from the controller. How do I accomplish this? Alternatively, is there a more direct route to this end?

**UPDATE**

Here is my partial:

```
<% if current_user.voted_for?(store) %>
        <%= link_to image_tag("followactive.png"), 
                { :controller => :stores, 
                :action => 'unfollow_from_index', :store_id => store.id},
                { :method => 'delete', :remote => true }%>
<% else %>
        <%= link_to image_tag("follow.png"), 
                { :controller => :stores, 
                :action => 'follow_from_index', :store_id => store.id},
                { :method => 'post', :remote => true} %>
<% end %>
```

Call to render partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'stores/favorite_index', :locals => {:store => s} %>
# while looping through @stores.each do |s|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you'll want your controller action to render javascript.  Do something like this:

```
def follow_or_unfollow
  @store = Store.find(params[:store_id])

  if current_user.voting_for?(@store)
    current_user.unvote_for(@store)
  else
    current_user.vote_for(@store)
  end

  respond_to |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and then in your views make a file called follow_or_unfollow.js and paste this in it:

```
$("#<%= @store.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'favorite_index', locals: {store: @store} ) %>");
```

note the "#" at the beginning of the jquery so it knows this is an ID.  Finally make sure _favorite_index.html.erb exists somewhere in the same directory and renders the new button state.

Comment: I think I'm really close with this, but I still don't see how I pass the store object to the partial from the js template? Just posted my partial.

Comment: Use '@store' instead of 'store' in both the js and your partial.

Comment: How can I do that though? `@store` is not defined in the `index` action. In the loop, I have to pass each store object to the partial as a local as shown above.

Comment: Ah didn't realize you were using this partial in another context.  In that case I think you can pass @store to the partial using a local.  I'll update the answer to show this.

Comment: Sorry should've been more clear in my question. So this works!....on the first request. Any subsequent follow or unfollow actions result in `undefined local variable or method 'store'` coming from the first line of the partial. Any idea why?

Comment: I've refactored it a bit.  You'll need to create voting_for? and unvote_for methods in the user model for this to work.  Best practice is probably to make this more restful by moving the controller logic to a vote_controller's create and destroy actions, and put corresponding create.js and destroy.js in the app/views/votes folder, but this should work.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for working through it. Thankfully I already had those methods for `voted_for?` and `unvote_for` as part of the ThumbsUp gem. Thanks again!